# Adding a new line between documents with hadoop getmerge

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to get a bunch of files from hadoop and merge them into one big file and I would like to have a newline between each document. 
`hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst> addnl` should do exactly that, but it does not seem to add a newline no matter what!
I also tried 
`hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst> -nl` After seeing this :https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7340
But this is also not working. Am I missing something? Does this work for anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with writing some code to do this (and not relying on the shell commands), you could amend the current FsShell.copyMergeToLocal method (which is what hadoop fs -getmerge is calling) to include a custom file separator string ("\n\n" in your case):

```
void copyMergeToLocal(String srcf, Path dst, String fileSeparatorString) throws IOException {
  Path srcPath = new Path(srcf);
  FileSystem srcFs = srcPath.getFileSystem(getConf());
  Path [] srcs = FileUtil.stat2Paths(srcFs.globStatus(srcPath), 
                                   srcPath);
  for(int i=0; i<srcs.length; i++) {
      FileUtil.copyMerge(srcFs, srcs[i], 
          FileSystem.getLocal(getConf()), dst, false, 
          getConf(), fileSeparatorString);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Following command worked for me:

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge -nl <src> <localdst>
```